# Wifi card not getting detected

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, intel, iwlwifi, airmon-ng

I'm using Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 on my laptop and installed Kali Linux 2020.2 on virtual box. My problem is when I run `sudo airmon-ng` it doesn't get detected, I get no output under PHY, Interface, Driver or Chipset. But on Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my HDD when I run the same command I get PHY(phy0), Interface(wlp2s0), Driver(iwlwifi), Chipset(Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)). How can I get Kali Linux on virtual box to detect my Wi-Fi card? I already installed the firmware through `sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi` and it's in the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host OS is controlling the WiFi adapter.

Since VirtualBox (nor any other virtualization software) has not implemented a virtual WiFi adapter, and your physical WiFi adapter is on a PCIe bus, the only way to get the Kali VM to control it would be to use PCI passthrough, which is complicated. And I think the PCI passthrough feature was removed from the newest major release of VirtualBox because it did not work well enough.

You might want to buy a USB-connected  Wi-Fi adapter that is known to support "monitor mode" in Linux. Then you can tell VirtualBox to hand over full control of that adapter to the VM. Only then you will be able to use the full functionality of airmon-ng or other WiFi monitoring/penetration tools from within a VM.

Comment: What if I run Kali Linux from a bootable USB drive, would I be able to access the inbuilt Wi-Fi card?

Comment: Yes you would. As long as the correct firmware file for the adapter is available, the adapter should be immediately usable. And for the firmware, jus make sure the “firmware-iwlwifi” package gets installed.